# Android Contacts White List

Tags: android, contacts

**Hello Everyone:**

I am developing an Android mobile application that has the following idea:
It turns the mobile phone into silent mode except for a number of contacts in the white list. How is that possible (if possible).
I have read that we can detect incoming and outgoing calls. However, how can I access the phonebook and specify the contacts?

**Thanx!**

Answer (score 2):

All your ideas are possible.
1. access phone-book: using content provider,there is a [example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ContactManager/) from android developer.
2.  detect incoming call : extend `PhoneStateListener` and rewrite its `onCallStateChanged (int state, String incoming Number)` function, where state is the current phone state, when it is equal `CALL_STATE_RINGING` ,that means there is a call in, in this function, you can comparing the incoming number(variable **incoming Number**) with your white list, if it matches, do your own operation like mute it or cancel it.

You need permissions to be set for all these in the Manifest File..

Comment: @AndroidKid, thank you for revising, so many mistakes since English is not my native language. ^_^

Comment: You are welcome... You may consider using a Dictionary or online translation service... It helps you improving a lot..